# How to rearrange attributes of an object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have an object like this:

```
user = {
  'a': 0,
  'b': 1,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4
}
```

I want to rearrange its properties like this:

```
user = {
  'c': 3,
  'a': 0,
  'b': 1,
  'd': 4
}
```

I don't want to create a new object instead I want to rearrange the attributes of the existing object.

Comment: The set of properties in an object don't really have a reliable ordering. It's generally based on the sequence of events that added the properties to the object, but even that is a very fragile behavior on which to base any sort of coding practice.

Comment: If you want a defined ordering, you can use an adjunct array to order the properties according to your needs and then sort the properties in a given object via that array after getting the property names via `Object.keys()`.

Comment: *"for some reasons"* - could you expand on what they are? This is likely an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Saying you want user.c to come before user.a is a bit like saying you want document.getElementById to come before document.querySelector.  In the context of an object, it doesn't make sense.  Use arrays (possibly of objects) to structure your data if you need order.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define the order of keys in a normal object. What you can do instead is to transform the `Object` into a `Map`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

> A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order — a for...of loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.

```
var user = {a: 0, b: 1, c: 3, d: 4};
var uMap = new Map([['c', user.c], ['a', user.a], ['b', user.b], ['d', user.d]]);
```

Or, you can turn your `Object` into an `Array` and work with it. The downside of this approach is that you have to remember the correct index position of the properties/what property corresponds to which position in the array:

```
var user = {a: 0, b: 1, c: 3, d: 4};
var uArr = [user.c, user.a, user.b, user.d];
```

Answer (score 1):

In a JavaScript object, you can't really order key/value pairs. They are stored in their own internal format and so the ordering can never really be relied upon.

I'm not sure what your exact use case is but if you need a guaranteed order of certain fields you could create an array that contains the field names in the order you require and use this to iterate through the object and fetch the values as you require.

Hope this helps!